# Discord.py bot not reading a cog

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a cog for my commands in my discord.py bot. I have looked at a few tutorials and cant seem to get it working. I get the error, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cog'`

**Code for main.py file**

```
bot.load_extension('Cog.Commands')
```

**Code for my commands.py file**

```
from discord.ext import commands

class Commands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx):
      await ctx.send("Hi!")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Commands(bot))
```

I know im probably missing something or changed something and im sorry for that. How can I get this working right so the error goes away? Thanks!

Comment: It's most likely either the case sensitivity explained in loloToster's answer or there is an error in the cog causing the cog to fail loading. Check the error it is throwing while loading the cog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idk if that's the case but try this:
Rename folder with cogs to `cogs` and replace

```py
bot.load_extension('Cog.Commands')
```

with:

```py
bot.load_extension('cogs.commands')
```

This is what I have and it is working. Also your cogs folder should be in directory that the `main.py` is in and if your `commands.py` starts with lower case the declaration of it should start with a lower case too ([API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension)).

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it working. I forgot to put the cog file in a folder lol

Comment: If this helped you should accept this answer for everyone else to see that this question was solved

Comment: Yeah it said i had to wait 5 minutes.